# how to write a super fast ascii file in C# if it contains 100000 lines of data?

Tags: c#

i have a code which generates random strings and numbers from random class in C#. and then writes it to a text file. how can i improve the performance?
the code is as follows:

```
    int i = 0;
    Record[] rec = new Record[100000];
    Class1 cl = new Class1();
    Random random = new Random();
    while (i < 100000)
    {
        rec[i].num1 = random.Next();
        rec[i].num2 = random.Next();
        rec[i].mult = rec[i].num1 * rec[i].num2;
        rec[i].rel = true;
        rec[i].name = cl.generateRandomString(1);
        rec[i].var_set = cl.generateRandomString(2);          
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.txt", true))
        {

            writer.Write(rec[i].name);
            writer.Write("   ");
            writer.Write(rec[i].var_set);
            writer.Write("   ");
            writer.Write(rec[i].num1);
            writer.Write("   ");
            writer.Write(rec[i].num2);
            writer.Write("   ");
            writer.Write(rec[i].mult);
            writer.Write("   "); 
            writer.WriteLine(rec[i].rel);
        }
        i++;
```

Comment: Show us some code. There's a million reasons why it could be slow, and we're not psychic.

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: your program will run faster if you stop writing to that file

Comment: @SP Given the actual facts in this question, you're comment is probably the best answer.

Comment: Store it in memory and then write it all out at once. 100000 lines should easily fit in memory.

Comment: @Kibbee - unless the 100000 lines are 1000000 characters long :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what happens when you do this:

```
Record[] rec = new Record[100000]; 
Class1 cl = new Class1(); 
Random random = new Random(); 
int i = 0;
while (i < 100000) 
{ rec[i].num1 = random.Next(); rec[i].var_set = cl.generateRandomString(2); i++; };

i = 0;
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.txt", true))
    {

        while ( i < 100000)
        {
        writer.Write(rec[i].name);
        writer.Write("   ");
        writer.Write(rec[i].var_set);
        writer.Write("   ");
        writer.Write(rec[i].num1);
        writer.Write("   ");
        writer.Write(rec[i].num2);
        writer.Write("   ");
        writer.Write(rec[i].mult);
        writer.Write("   "); 
        writer.WriteLine(rec[i].rel);

        i++;
        };
    }
```

**EDIT - another option:**

```
Record[] rec = new Record[100000]; 
Class1 cl = new Class1(); 
Random random = new Random(); 
int i = 0;
while (i < 100000) 
{ rec[i].num1 = random.Next(); rec[i].var_set = cl.generateRandomString(2); i++; };

File.WriteAllLines ( "important.txt", (from r in rec select r.name + "   " + 
r.var_set  + "   " + r.num1 + "   " + r.num2 + "   " + r.mult + 
"   " + r.rel).ToArray());
```

Comment: i am trying to do a small test to see how fast i can write a text file in C# my system deals with large amount of data (file size of 50MB (100,000 Records) it takes about 2-3mins using c#, as per the above code). the above program generates random numbers and strings (c1.generaterandomstring(2).My program (in future) will read the database and then write it into a text file. I have a feeling that this could potentially become a bottleneck.

Comment: not sure I understand... I thought you wanted to write faster than with your code... did you try the code from EDIT... if yes, was it faster than the code you posted ?

Answer (score 5):

Based on the code you supplied in the comment for @Ben, I got this code that you are using.

```
Record[] rec = new Record[100000]; 
Class1 cl = new Class1(); 
Random random = new Random(); 
while (i < 100000) 
{ 
    rec[i].num1 = random.Next();
    rec[i].var_set = cl.generateRandomString(2);
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.txt", true)) 
    { 
        writer.Write(rec[i].name); 
        writer.Write(" "); 
    } 
    i++;
}
```

The biggest problem I see is that you are opening the streamwriter for each iteration of the loop.  You probably want to change your code to something like this so that the file is only opened once.

```
int i = 0;
Record[] rec = new Record[100000]; 
Class1 cl = new Class1(); 
Random random = new Random(); 
StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter("important.txt", true);

try
{
    while (i < 100000) 
    { 
        rec[i].num1 = random.Next();
        rec[i].var_set = cl.generateRandomString(2);
        sr.Write(rec[i].name); 
        sr.Write(" "); 
        i++;
    }
}
finally
{
    sr.Close();
}
```

Comment: A couple capitalization errors there, but I think you've hit on the problem.  Another possible improvement would be to use a temporary variable instead of array lookups every time `rec[i]` is mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't really meant to compile, just to explain the basic issues. Feel free to fix the syntax, I don't have an IDE on this machine, and C# isn't my native language.

Answer (score 1):

[`System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) is incredibly fast.

But probably your performance problems are caused by formatting your output, and not actually writing the file (file writes are very fast when disk write cache is enabled).

Comment: or possibly the speed of your random source,

Comment: the program is as follows : 1st is the for loop for 100000 times after this generates random string and generates random number and the writes the string and number to the file. Then the same process repeates till 100000 times.

Comment: Record[] rec = new Record[100000];
        Class1 cl = new Class1();
        Random random = new Random();
        while (i < 100000)
        {
            rec[i].num1 = random.Next();
            rec[i].var_set = cl.generateRandomString(2); using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.txt", true))
            {
                
                writer.Write(rec[i].name);
                writer.Write("   ");
            }
            i++;

Comment: @user: Are you doing anything else with the array?  If not, you can store just one `Record` instance at a time, and replace it with the next one, instead of making an array.

Answer (score 0):

You really should take the time to edit your question and include the code from the comment.

So that's your current code as from the comment:

```
Record[] rec = new Record[100000]; 
Class1 cl = new Class1(); 
Random random = new Random(); 
while (i < 100000) 
{ 
    rec[i].num1 = random.Next();
    rec[i].var_set = cl.generateRandomString(2);
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.txt", true))
    { 
        writer.Write(rec[i].name); 
        writer.Write(" "); 
    } 
    i++; 
}
```

What is wrong with it is the fact that you're opening, writing and closing the file 100000 times for each iteration of the outer loop.

**Put the open/close logic outside the loop:**

```
Record[] rec = new Record[100000]; 
Class1 cl = new Class1(); 
Random random = new Random(); 
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("important.txt", true))
{ 
    while (i < 100000) 
    { 
        rec[i].num1 = random.Next();
        rec[i].var_set = cl.generateRandomString(2);
        writer.Write(rec[i].name); 
        writer.Write(" "); 
        i++; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The performance is always application specific, only you can really define what is "superfast". By the way one of the solutions + already offered by @Ben is to have a big chunk of data, like a 20.000 lines per chunk and write them in 5 shots, pr one big chunk of data of 100.000 lines if can afford them in your app, why not?  Could be good solution too, but it's very your context specific, so how says Rico Mariani: "measure, measure, measure".

Regards.